# Oracleでユーザー作成時にデフォルト表領域を作成できない

Tags: oracle

```
SQL> CREATE USER "SQL1" PROFILE "DEFAULT" IDENTIFIED BY "sql1"
  2      DEFAULT TABLESPACE "EXAMPLE"
  3     TEMPORARY TABLESPACE "TEMP"
  4    　 QUOTA UNLIMITED ON "EXAMPLE" ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
```

上記のコードを入力しユーザーを作成しようとしたところ、**ORA-00959: 表領域'EXAMPLE'は存在しません**というエラーメッセージが表示されデフォルト領域を作成することができません。ユーザーの作成方法はこの方法で間違ってないと思うのですがなぜでしょうか。教えて頂きたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

すでに理解されていると思いますが、`CREATE USER`の`DEFAULT TABLESPACE`は既に作成済みの表領域を指定するものです。

表領域`USERS`を使うことは問題ではありませんが(※)、`CREATE TABLESPACE`で表領域を作成することができます。

※`DEFAULT TABLESPACE`を省略して`SYSTEM`表領域を使うことになるよりは、はるかに良い方法です。

Answer (score 0):

表領域を調べたところEXAMPLEはエラーメッセージの通り存在しませんでした。そのため、元からあるUSERS領域を使うことで解決することができました。